# Change html to normal text in UITextView xcode

Tags: html, uitextview

How do I change html code to normal text in UITextView in Xcode?

By the way I load the html in the feed of a site.

I have the html code:

```
<p>
    TestLocatie-1, Lelystad Adres: &#60;adres&#62;, &#60;postcode&#62; &#60;plaatsnaam&#62;     Oppervlakte: &#60;opp&#62; m² Bestemming: &#60;omschrijving bestemming, omschrijving bestemming&#62; Omschrijving: &#60;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ulliam corper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo [&#8230;]
</p>
<p>
  The post <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.flexstorez.nl/testlocatie-1/">TestLocatie-1</a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.flexstorez.nl">FlexStorez</a>.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this code. A few people say apple will be reject your app if you use this, but there are people, where apple accept the code.

```
self.textview.editable = NO;
self.textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
[self.textview setValue: yourHTMLString forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
```

Comment: Does this code help you, or do you need help with it?